# Exploiting C99 VLAs to cause stack overflow

Tags: c

In [my project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/png2jpeg/) one of the command-line arguments is loaded into a C99 VLA (variable-length array) as shown in the example code below.

My question is: can this be exploited? If yes, I'd like to be shown how and also how to patch it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    char msg[strlen(argv[1]) + 1];

    strcpy(msg, argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: As the question is currently you just dump some code here and ask for exploiting and fixing which makes it off-topic. It might be better received if you show more of your efforts, i.e. explain why you think it can or cannot be exploited and thus mainly ask if you understood the underlying concepts correctly.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich But if I already knew, then I wouldn't ask. And the question is general (just like the code), so a general answer will help future visitors.

Comment: Perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate?

Comment: @NeilSmithline I have already [posted there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/125930/102756) for a code review of the complete program. I came here in the hope that I would get a specific security-related answer to my usage of VLAs, hence the example code.

I am torn between keeping the current code (which I believe is quite elegant) and using `FILENAME_MAX` with bounds-checked string functions from C11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see a stack buffer overflow (or any other vulnerability) in the code you have presented.

Comment: But importantly for the OP - this doesn't mean it has no vulnerabilities or can't be exploited!!